# Want to Make Video File From Sequences of Images and Audio file

Tags: objective-c

I want to make a Video file of format (.avi or .mp4) from sequences of Images and audio file(in a wave format) in Objective C. I have tried different methods but it does not work. Can anybody give me a direction of work So that i can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the QTMovie class, included in the QTKit.framework. It offers a convenient method:

```
- (void)addImage:(NSImage *)image forDuration:(QTTime)duration withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

You can create a new QTMovie, than use the method above to add different images to this movie. Writing it to a video file is as easy as calling:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)fileName withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

Anyway, this will not allow you to write an AVI file, but will create a MOV instead.

Answer (score 0):

*QTMovie* is for Mac OS X. For iOS, it's quite more complicated. You'll have to use *AVFoundation* : AVAssetXxX (Writer, WriterInput, etc.)
You can find answers around the web on how to make a movie from images. But I didn't check about the sound.